# How can I superscript st to digit 1 in java?

Tags: java

I want to write a date in which I want to superscript the string "st". Is there any unicode available for that?

Any suggestions will be appreciated
Thank You!

Comment: You can use unicode in your strings/source files. How are you creating the string?

Comment: @matt I am using a string r=date+"unicode here"; in which date contains 1 and I want to superscript st to 1

Comment: You can literally copy and paste "1ˢᵗ" into your java source file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the codes.

- ˢ is "\u02e2"
- ᵗ is "\u1d57"
- ᵈ is "\u1d48"
- ʳ is "\u02b3"
- ⁿ is "\u207F"
- ʰ is "\u02B0"

I found them here [unicode-table](https://unicode-table.com/en/02B3/) which you can search by name.

I think that covers all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is:

`ˢᵗ`

For further characters you should visit the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) or the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1).

Comment: Can you please elaborate as I have already seen this article but was not able to understand. Like what is the unicode?

Comment: In the normal case you don't need to know it. You can just copy-paste the characters you need into your java code.